# While creating a table in WordPress DB site gives 500 error

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, plugins

I'm learning how to create a plugin for WordPress. I want to create a table in WordPress DB. But after writing a code for developing a table site shows 500 error. I tried to create a table using a MySQL Workbench but then the site is not working. I try to do that in other function and init that while plugin activation but It hasn't worked. Here is a code for creating a table:

```
function my_plugin_start(){

    $status_url = get_option('');
    preg_match('/^http(s)?\/\/[^\/]+\/(.*)$/i', $status_url, $matches);

    $real_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    preg_match('/^\/(.+)(\?.+)$/i', $real_url, $uri_matches);

    if ($uri_matches[1] == $matches[2]){
        if(isset($_GET['dcode'])){
            start_download();
        }
        else {
            interkassa_process();
        }
    }

// The code for creating a table

    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_product_base";

    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
      UNIQUE KEY id (id) AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      cost VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

    );";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'cottage/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);

    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_add_admin_menu');
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_start');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this modified code**

```
function my_plugin_start(){

    $status_url = get_option('');
    preg_match('/^http(s)?\/\/[^\/]+\/(.*)$/i', $status_url, $matches);

    $real_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    preg_match('/^\/(.+)(\?.+)$/i', $real_url, $uri_matches);

    if ($uri_matches[1] == $matches[2]){
        if(isset($_GET['dcode'])){
            start_download();
        }
        else {
            interkassa_process();
        }
    }

// The code for creating a table

    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_product_base";

    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
      UNIQUE KEY id (id) AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      cost VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

    );";

        require_once(ABSPATH . '/cottage/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);

    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_add_admin_menu');
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_start');
```